# Finding substring with equal number of characters

Tags: c, optimization, substring

For a problem where we need to find number of substrings of a string where number of repetitions of each character should be same. Given string consists of only 3 characters(A,B,C).

I could make it only with an algo of O(n^2).

```
for(;i<len;i++)
{
 if(s[i]=='A')
 ac++;
 else if(s[i]=='B')
 bc++;
 else if(s[i]=='C')
 cc++;
 for(k=i+1;k<len;k++)
 {
  if(s[k]=='A')
  ac++;
  else if(s[k]=='B')
  bc++;
  else if(s[k]=='C')
  cc++;
  if(ac==bc && bc==cc)
  {count++;}
 }
 ac=0;bc=0;cc=0;
}
```

It takes a very long time to calculate for longer strings(for in range of 10^5). Please help in getting a better solution.

Comment: [This problem has been solved decades ago.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm) Please put more effort into your research.

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to implement a hash map in C, you can solve this in what I believe is O(n).

Keep a normalised count of all As and Bs. By normalised I mean that the C count in always zero. The C count is also implied, because your string only contains As, Bs and Cs and the current string length must therefore be A + B + C.

Start with a hash map with a count of 1 for the (0, 0) count.

Pass through the string once. When you pass an A, increment the A count. When you pass a B, increment the B count. When you pass a C, decrement both the A and B counts. Add the current count (A, B) to the hash map if it doesn't exist and increment it.

To illustrate:

```
        0   0
A       1   0  *--------------
B       1   1        valid
A       2   1        substring
C       1   0  *--------------
A       2   0
```

Finally, loop over all hash map entries and add the triangle sum of that entry to your overall count. By triangle sum `t(n)`, I mean: `t(1) = 0`, `t(2) = 1`, t(3) = `2 + 1`, t(4) = `3 + 2 + 1` and so on. That reflects the fact that the hash entries represent the borders of valid substrings and that you can merge adjacent substrings:

```
ACB      ABC      BCA      BCA       +4
   ACBABC   ABCBCA   BCABCA          +3
     ACBABCBCA   ABCBCABCA           +2
         ACBABCBCABCA                +1
```

In pseudo C:

```
int nsubseq(const char *str)
{
    Map *map = map_new();
    const char *p;

    int aa = 0;
    int bb = 0;

    map_add(map, key(aa, bb), 1);

    for (p = str; *p; p++) {
        if (*p == 'A') aa++;
        else if (*p == 'B') bb++;
        else if (*p == 'C') aa--, bb--;

        int *q = map_find(map, key(aa, bb));
        if (q) {
            *q = *q + 1;
        } else {
            map_add(map, key(aa, bb), 1);
        }
    }

    int count = 0;        
    for (int *p = map_begin(map); p; p = map_next(map)) {
        int n = *p;

        while (n--) count += n;
    }

    map_delete(map);

    return count;
}
```

(That's actually real C, just that you have to implement all `map` functions. Or use an existing hash map implementation, of course.)

The performance of the code depends on the hash map implementation, but with a hash size of 4096, I can scan a string of one million equally distributed As, Bs and Cs in less than a second. This is the optmum case; performance goes down the less evenly distributed a string is. Corner cases without hits (only As or only As and Bs), where basically every character creates a new entry in the hash map, take about twelve times longer.

If the entries to the hash were lists of indices instead of counts, you could even extract the values of the substrings, although for a string with 100k entries, that would be overkill.